# Тип файловой системы в /sys/class?

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Как узнать в /sys/class тип файловой системы НЕ примонтированного диска?

Comment: 1. вероятно, подразумевался не диск, а раздел диска. 2. вероятно, никак. зачем в этой псевдо-файловой системе подобная информация?

Comment: А blkid не поможет отцу русской демократии?

Comment: @donRumata Подозреваю, товарищ из своего приложения хочет мониторить состояние ФС, и тут читать sysFS как бы надёжнее, нежели полагаться на присутствие утилиты.

Comment: @dsnk так точно, парсинг sysfs надежнее.

Comment: Ну а что тогда мешает посмотреть сорец этой самой blkid? Раз она умеет видеть непримонтированные фс, то это где-то же прописано в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить имя файловой системы можно с помощью blkid.h

Пример:

```
QString type;
const char *gettype;
blkid_probe pr = blkid_new_probe_from_filename("/dev/sda1");

pr = blkid_new_probe_from_filename("/dev/sda1");
blkid_do_probe(pr);

blkid_probe_lookup_value(pr, "TYPE", &gettype, NULL);

type = gettype;

blkid_free_probe(pr);

return type;
```

Answer (score 0):

программа *linux*, насколько мне известно, не занимается идентификацией файловых систем «про запас», т.е., на непримонтированных блочных устройствах. поэтому и из псевдофайловой системы *sysfs* она такую информацию не предоставляет.

подтверждением может служить вызов программы *blkid*, которая (в частности) идентифицирует файловые системы и на непримонтированных блочных устройствах.

судя по выводу команды (оставлены только существенные строки):

```
$ sudo strace -e open blkid
open("/dev/sr0", O_RDONLY)              = -1 ENOMEDIUM (No medium found)
open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY)             = 4
open("/dev/sda5", O_RDONLY)             = 4
open("/dev/sdb1", O_RDONLY)             = 4
```

программа каждый раз при запуске читает информацию непосредственно с разделов, вероятно, идентифицируя при этом (возможно) находящиеся на разделах файловые системы.